# Unable to get associative array value by key

Tags: php, html, arrays, echo, associative-array

I Have 2 pages, First page is to capture 1 - 5 Star ratings.

The Second is to see the stats, on the Questions that were asked, so we can see how man people select Star 1, how many people selected Star 2, etc.

On the First page when the person hit's submit, my PHP creates a text file corresponding to each question (Question1, Question2, etc.) that will store the values of 1 - 5 rating of what the person rated.

On the Second page which is where I'm having the problem, I was able to get the values from the text file as an associative array:

-var_dump -

```
array(3) { ["2 "]=> int(1) ["5 "]=> int(2) ["3 "]=> int(1) }
```

print_r

```
Array ( [2 ] => 1 [5 ] => 2 [3 ] => 1 )
```

The ["2 "], ["5 "] and ["3 "] are the ratings that's in my text file, the int() is how many time the rating was counted in my text file that's how I'm getting the amount of people clicked on the rating for each question.

What I'm trying to do is when I echo the Array with for example key ["2"] for the integer to be display! but every time I attempt to do this I get an error or I get nothing, Most common Error I get is:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\Xampp\htdocs\ECwebpages\Survey-Stats\Survey-Stats.php on line 101
>   NULL

If you need more info please do let me know. I'll have the code below!

```php
 <?php

          $counter = 1; 

          if (file_exists("../Question1.txt") && file_exists("../Question10.txt")){



              $files = "../Question1.txt";


              $lines=file($files);

              $vals = array_count_values($lines);

              foreach($vals as $answers => $keyss ){}

              var_dump($vals["2 "]);



              foreach($lines as $linescntnt => $key){


                  if($key == 1){
                      //count how many poeple click on star 1 and place here 

                      if($answers == '1'){
                          //display how many people clicked on the First rating
                          echo  "<td>".$vals."</td>";
                      }else{
                          echo "<td>-<td>";
                      }
                  }

                  if ($key == 2){
                      //count how many poeple click on star 1 and place here 
                      if($answers == '2'){
                            //display how many people clicked on the Second rating
                          echo  "<td>-</td>";
                      }else{
                          echo "<td>-<td>";
                      }

                  }


                  if($key == 3){
                      //count how many poeple click on star 1 and place here 
                       if($answers == '3'){
                             //display how many people clicked on the Third rating
                        echo  "<td>".$answers."</td>";
                      }else{
                          echo "<td>-<td>";
                      }
                  }
                  if($key == 4){
                      //count how many poeple click on star 1 and place here 
                       if($answers == '4'){
                             //display how many people clicked on the Fourth rating
                        echo  "<td>".$answers."</td>";
                      }else{
                          echo "<td>-<td>";
                      }
                  }
                  if($key == 5){
                      //count how many poeple click on star 1 and place here 
                       if($answers == '5'){
                             //display how many people clicked on the Fifth rating
                        echo  "<td>".$answers."</td>";
                      }else{
                          echo "<td>-<td>";
                      }
                  }


              }
          }



    ?>
```

Comment: Way to much code. Strip out all that is not needed and create a minimal verifiable complete example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is a single dimension array, so you just need `$vals["2 "]` instead of `$vals["0"]["2 "]`

Comment: @aynber That's what I've done as well and still doesn't work.

Comment: @Andreas made the changes

Comment: @aynber When I do `$vals["2 "]` I get **Notice: Undefined index: 2 in D:\Xampp\htdocs\ECwebpages\Survey-Stats\Survey-Stats.php on line 94
NULL**

Comment: The var_dump shows your keys being `["2 "]` `["3 "]` and `["5 "]` **Note the trailing space**  You could change how the keys are populated or change the conditions that you are using to `if($key == "1 ")`, `if($key == "2 ")`, etc

Comment: @mtr.web I have noticed that but when I do `$vals["2 "]` it does work, also `if($key == "2 ")` is not my problem because that's part of the `foreach $lines` my key `["2 "]` is part of `foreach $vals`, to simplify, I have 2 different foreach, one for getting the files and one for handling the values.

Comment: @ozzy you're looking for numeric values in the conditions, but populating your array index with string values, which, with the trailing space, will never match up. When you build up your array *remove the white spaces or convert to a numeric value*.

Comment: `foreach($vals as $answers => $keyss ){}` Whats that supposeed to be not doing

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well I can tell you what it is doing for now, I'm using it to compare value from file `if($answers == '1'){
                     <td> how many people clicked </td>
                  }else{
                      echo "<td>-<td>";
                  }`

Comment: @Malovich I am unable to trim and or remove White spacing from Keys, would you be able to show me an example?

Comment: @Malovich I was able to remove the white space with `  $a = array_map("trim", array_keys($vals));` but then my array turns into `array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "5" [2]=> string(1) "3" }`. "string()" is suppose to show my duplicate count from file.

Answer (score 1):

After some time of trial and error I was finally able to make this work, @Malovich explained in the comments ("When you build up your array remove the white spaces or convert to a numeric value."), and so I `trim()` my file `$lines`:

```
$files = "../Question1.txt";

$lines=file($files);

 --trim-->   $trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$lines); <--
```

I then continued and did my count:

```
$vals = array_count_values($trimmed_array);
```

and finally in order to get my values from key to show the amount of how many people clicked the specific star I did:

```
 if(isset($vals[1])){

    echo "<td>".$vals[1]."</td>";

 }else{

       echo "<td>0</td>";

  }
```

$vals is the array and the key ([1],[2], etc.) is to get the integer that was created when I used array_count_values().

```html
   if (file_exists("../Question1.txt") && file_exists("../Question10.txt")){
   
   $files = "../Question2.txt";
   
   $lines=(file($files));
   
   $trimmed_array=array_map('trim',$lines);
   
   $vals = array_count_values($trimmed_array);
   
   foreach($vals as $answers => $keys){

    }

    if(isset($vals[1])){

      echo "<td>".$vals[1]."</td>";

    }else{
      echo "<td>0</td>";
    }

    if(isset($vals[2])){

    echo "<td>".$vals[2]."</td>";

    }else{
    echo "<td>0</td>";
    }

    etc...
  
  }else {
  
    echo ' <td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>';
    
}
```